# access "current" index while updating array elements with mongo

Tags: mongodb

I would like to add an `id` field to all elements of an array. No problem to add it without a value:

`db.getCollection('mycollection').update({}, {$set : {"data.gastroscopy.$[].id": null }}`)

But what I actually need is to set the id value to the element index obtaining something like:

```
{
  data: {
    gastroscopy: [
      {
        id: 1,
        foo: 'bar'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        foo: 'zar'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        foo: 'car'
      },
    ]
  }
}

I could not find a way to refer the index and use it. Is it possible?

thank you
```

Comment: Are you want update/add id key ??

Comment: yes an incremental integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Okay, But really read the bottom as well

It's *"possible"*, but the only way you can make that happen in a *single statement* is [using MongoDB 4.2 or greater](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline):

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').updateMany(
  {},
  [{ "$set": {
    "data.gastrocopy": {
      "$map": {
        "input": {
          "$range": [0, { "$size": "$data.gastrocopy" }]
        },
        "in": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$data.gastocopy", "$$this" ] },
            { "id": { "$add": [ "$$this", 1 ] } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}]
)
```

So the main trick is the [`$range`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) operator which can generate an array of what is essentially the index values,  then you use that with a [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) in order to transpose those values into the original array content. Note however the usage of these aggregation operators within any "update" statement is a relatively new feature ( at writing ) and requires MongoDB 4.2 or greater.

Otherwise you basically are looping the collection and writing back each document, ideally with `bulkWrite()`:

```
var batch = [];

db.getCollection('mycollection').find().forEach(doc => {

   batch.push({
     "updateOne": {
       "filter": { _id: doc._id },
       "udpate": {
         "$set": { "data.gastrocopy": doc.data.gastrocopy.map((e,i) => ({ ...e, id: i+1 })) }
       }
     }
   });

   if (batch.length >= 1000) {
      db.getCollection('mycollection').bulkWrite(batch);
      batch = [];
   }

})

if (batch.length > 0) {
  db.getCollection('mycollection').bulkWrite(batch);
  batch = [];
}
```

Basically the same basic mechanic, but of course done iteratively and by reading each document back to the client since there is no other way to do that in earlier MongoDB versions.

I'm also not a fan of either as both do run an inherent risk of *overwriting* existing content that *might* have been added by another process in between the read and the write. The MongoDB 4.2 "aggregate" syntax has a *lesser* chance, but I believe it still does have *some* chance in high volume environments.

So implement at your own risk. You can make some things a *"little"* better with positional updates, but any update on "index value" is never *truly* reliable. Again it all depends on your actual usage of the "said" arrays.

---

### Important

I would note that I struggle to see the utility of such an update though. Arrays are after-all **Arrays** and therefore inherrently have an index position ( Notably as `n-1`, which is the standard convention ). If you want to match things by an index position, then there are already built in operations in MongoDB that do that, without needing to add an arbitrary value for storage.

You might look at ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) and operators like [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) for projection or even aggregation [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) to realize that what you are trying to create already exists. About the ***only*** worthwhile place would be with a query expression like:

```
{ "data.gastrocopy": { "$elemMatch": { "id": { "$gte": 0, "$lte": 3 } } } }
```

And then really only when you created an index on that `id` field. That would be useful are more performant than other "array index based" methods as mentioned which already exist.

So it really depends on what you want to use this for as to whether you really need such an update or not.

Comment: Thank you Neil for your accuracy. My need is part of a big data migration process. The destination db its behind a webapp that is supposed to let the user export data from json (raw) to a "multiflat" structure (multisheet excel or relational database). Every deep nested array will generate a sheet or a table and I need primary and foreign keys. I cannot generate the ids on the fly while parsing the json for the export because they may change so I need to store them. Hence, my legacy data need to have an ID in objects belonging to arrays in order to be imported. I will go for the bulkWrite()!